# jQuery change column order based on td class

Tags: jquery, class, html-table

I have a 3 columns HTML table and all TDs have a class:

How can I swap TD with class "col1" and TD class "col2"?

Here is a sample table (please note there are some colspans):

```
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">header</td>
        <td class="col2">header col2</td>
        <td class="col3">header col3</td>
        <td class="col1">header col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">row header 1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="col2">any text </td>
        <td class="col3">any text </td>
        <td class="col1">any text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row header 2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="col2">any text </td>
        <td class="col3">any text </td>
        <td class="col1">any text</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

All I want to do, is to swap TD.col1 with TD.col2 and display the table.

Comment: You can use the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to do this. If you require a more concrete example, please add your HTML code, along with the JS you tried already

Comment: Thanks, Rory, I added the sample table but I don't know javascript or jquery enough to get what I need.

Comment: Ok - I added an answer for you

Comment: Since the problem is solved, I put here a link to jsfiddle with the resulting code:

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lzwojmb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you need you can select all the `.col1` elements, then use `insertBefore()` to move them before the sibling `.col2`, like this:

```js
$('.col1').each(function() {
  $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev('.col2'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">header</td>
      <td class="col2">header col2</td>
      <td class="col1">header col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">row header 1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="col2">any text col2</td>
      <td class="col1">any text col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row header 2</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="col2">any text col2</td>
      <td class="col1">any text col1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: We are almost there! this works only on adiacent columns. What about non adiacent columns? This is my fault: sorry. I edited the table again to make it more similar to my needs.

Comment: In that case change `prev()` to `prevAll()`

Comment: perfect! thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can make an array of  class and **Sort** array according to your need to do this using javascript.

Comment: my problem is how to sort the columns using the classes and not the indexes (since there are some colspans). I searched all around but find only sorting rows.